# Finite difference method

Tags: derivatives, optimization, numerical-methods

I wanted to ask something regarding the finite difference approximation. I used the finite difference to calculate the numerical derivatives of my function. The finite difference is given by the following formula:

\begin{equation}
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
\end{equation}

The value of $h$ is questionable. In theory we should take it as small as possible, but I am not sure if we can just pick random different values for $h$ and try to see which one works better or if there is any "rule" or constraint to pick up a good value of $h$.

With Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you can obtain instabilities occurring when you take the limit with $h$. In fact if you are working with pdes you have von Neumann stability criteria for how small the grid steps are. In my own work I have just played around with the step size, and indeed with adaptive schemes (step size is determined by the problem itself and the step size is updated accordingly).

Answer (score 6):

If you are using one side finite differences for evaluating the derivative, the smallest step size should be $$h=x\sqrt{\epsilon}$$ where $\epsilon$ stands for the machine accuracy ($\epsilon$ being the smallest number such that $1+\epsilon > 1$).

This is related to the truncation error which comes from higher terms in the Taylor series expansion $$f(x+h)=f(x)+h f'(x)+\frac 12h^2f''(x)+\frac 16h^3f'''(x)$$ whence $$\begin{equation}
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(x)+\frac 12 h f''(x)
\end{equation}$$

If you can afford two function evaluations for the derivative, it is much better to use $$f'(x)=\begin{equation}
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}
\end{equation}$$ which will be more accurate and which will give you the second derivative for almost free. In such a case, you could choose $$h=x \sqrt[3]{\epsilon }$$

Comment: What do you do when you want to evaluate the derivative at x=0?

Comment: what step-size value should be used for second order one-side and central finite differences?

Answer (score 0):

A [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815113/is-there-a-general-formula-for-estimating-the-step-size-h-in-numerical-different/819015#819015) with a method for finding the optimal values of $h$.

In this case a process method will result in $h = \sqrt \frac{4 \epsilon}{M_2}$ where $\epsilon$ is the error in measurements of the function (usually machine accuracy, unless you measure your function with noise) and $M_2$ is a bound on the second derivative on the appropriate interval.